# Keynote files stopped opening and cannot be renamed

Tags: finder, catalina, keynote

I have Keynote files that were working well. If I right-click and select "Open with Keynote", they are normal, everything OK. But if I double click on them, they don't open even though Keynote is the default app. Their icons also show as blank white icons. I cannot rename them in Finder, but can do it once I open them in Keynote.

How do I get them back to normal? Renaming and opening as usual.

Thanks in advance

I'm on MacOS Catalina with Keynote 10.2.

Comment: Have you tried to click on Get Info -> And change the default application from Open With and Change all. After that, relaunch finder and try to open in normal, it should work

Comment: Yes, I did try that :( but it didn't solve. In the end I found a workaround that was copying / pasting the slides into a different presentation. I just hope this doesn't happen again